# Document title overwrites Item title when updating

Tags: document-library, content-type, document

I'm having problems with a custom content type that inherits the "Document"-content type.

The document properties (such as title and tags) overwrites the SharePoint properties when the item is updated (E.g. changing properties or approving the item)

Here is an example of how the error happens:

- Create a document (docx) and sets the property title in Word to "Hello World".
- Upload the document to a document library, setting the content type to my custom content type and changing the title from the suggested "Hello World", to "Hello Oslo".
- Save the document and can see in the list that the title is of the item is "Hello Oslo"
- But: If I now change another property on the item, or approves the document, the title is changed back to "Hello World".
- If I use the out-of-the-box content type "Document" or upload a *.doc-document, the title remains "Hello Oslo".

Any thoughts on what the problem might be?

This is an on-prem installation of SharePoint 2013, and the problem is present in all environments (Development, Test, QA and Prod).